# Characteristic subgroup of nilpotent group that is not invariant under powering

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-algebras, nilpotent-groups

I want an example of a nilpotent group $G$, a characteristic subgroup $H$, and a prime number $p$ such that:

- $G$ is $p$-powered, i.e., every element of $G$ has a unique $p^{th}$ root in $G$.
- $H$ is not $p$-powered. In this case, it would mean that there exists an element of $H$ that does not have any $p^{th}$ root in $H$.

Note that there do not exist any abelian examples, because in an abelian $p$-powered group, the $p^{th}$ root map is an automorphism and hence preserves every characteristic subgroup.

The intuitive reasoning for why there shouldn't be any examples: even though the $p^{th}$ root map is not an automorphism, it seems possible generally to find automorphisms that behave a lot like this map to a sufficient extent that characteristic subgroups must be preserved under taking $p^{th}$ roots.

The intuitive reasoning for why there may well be examples: nilpotent groups can in principle rigidify a lot of powering structure.

I don't know which side to believe.

PS: There are certainly characteristic subgroups of non-nilpotent groups with this property. For instance, let $G = GA^+(1,\mathbb{R})$ (the identity component of the affine group of degree one over the reals, i.e., maps of the form $x \mapsto ax + b, a > 0, a,b \in \mathbb{R}$), and let $H$ be the subgroup comprising those elements where $a$ is rational. $H$ is characteristic in $G$, $G$ is powered over all primes, and $H$ is not powered over any prime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists such example (thus also disproving Conjecture 4.1.28 [here](http://files.vipulnaik.com/thesis/thesis.pdf)).

Indeed there exists a nonzero nilpotent Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with rational coefficients whose automorphism group $A$ is unipotent (references (1,2) below). Therefore $\mathfrak{g}$ admits an $A$-invariant $\mathbf{Q}$-defined proper subalgebra $\mathfrak{l}$ such that the induced $A$-action on $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$ is trivial.

Let $G$ is the corresponding unipotent $\mathbf{Q}$-group ($G_K$ can be defined by endowing $\mathfrak{g}_K$ with the group law defined by the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula) and $L_\mathbf{Q}$ the corresponding subgroup, so that $\mathrm{Aut}(G_\mathbf{Q})=A_{\mathbf{Q}}$. Then $L_\mathbf{Q}$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G_\mathbf{Q}$ and the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(G_\mathbf{Q})$ on $G_\mathbf{Q}/L_\mathbf{Q}$ is trivial. It follows that every subgroup of $G_\mathbf{Q}$ containing $L_\mathbf{Q}$ is also a characteristic subgroup. So, if we define $H\subset G_\mathbf{Q}$ as the inverse image of an infinite cyclic subgroup of $G_\mathbf{Q}/L_\mathbf{Q}$, then $H$ is not $p$-divisible (hence not $p$-powered) for any prime $p$, while $G_\mathbf{Q}$ is $p$-powered for all primes $p$.

For those who rather like Lie groups: if we perform the same construction in the real case, we get $H\subset G_\mathbf{R}$, where $G_\mathbf{R}$ is a simply connected nilpotent Lie group, $H$ is a closed proper subgroup closed under the whole group of continuous group automorphisms of $G_\mathbf{R}$.

---

**References**

((1)) ([link](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183531386), [MR link](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=249544)) JL Dyer, A nilpotent Lie algebra with nilpotent automorphism group, Bulletin of the
American Mathematical Society 76 (1970) 52–56

((2)) [(MR link)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=294425) Favre, Gabriel
Une algèbre de Lie caractéristiquement nilpotente de dimension 7. (French) 
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B 274 (1972)

Comment: Note that it's based on the same idea as your solvable example: one choice of group containing the derived subgroup, assuming that the action on [some nontrivial part of] the abelianization is trivial. The only difference is that in the nilpotent world one need to struggle a little further to find the relevant examples; fortunately the cumbersome computational work had already been done (cf references).